# Converting MP3 to Ogg in CentOS

Tags: linux, unix, multimedia

We need to play MP3 files in [jPlayer](https://github.com/jplayer/jPlayer) without using Flash as a fallback.

For playing these files with Firefox, I want to convert it to [Ogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg). Do you guys have any options/alternative for this? I tried to use dir2ogg in CentOS, but it says "no DECODER found for MP3".

Please recommend a tool for converting MP3 to Ogg in CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) for this:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp3 -codec:a libvorbis -qscale:a 8 output.ogg
```

Note though that you should really convert from the lossless source, not an MP3.  You're losing another level of quality by using a lossy codec on a file that was already compressed with a lossy codec.

Also, given the time of the question, I assume you wanted to use Vorbis for the codec.  For anyone finding this answer now, consider [Opus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185598/how-to-convert-an-mp3-file-to-an-ogg-opus-file).  It will fit in your Ogg container, but has much higher quality for a given bitrate.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on converting using FFMPEG.

Comment: @rao.ghuge, Just run `ffmpeg`, with your input file as your MP3, and your output file as OGG with whatever quality and other settings you want.  Nothing more to it!  http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#basicaudio

Comment: I installed FFMPEG on CentOS and converted MP3 files to OGG. But these OGG files are not being played in JPlayer in FF Browser.

Comment: @RaoG, Can you post a sample file somewhere?  I'd recommend opening a new question, and including a link to your sample file.  There's probably something up with the encoding settings used.

Comment: Shocked about negatives without comments for a tool that does the job... Thank you for the answer, Brad

Comment: good suggestion: opus - I use ffmpeg for many things, and am using Centos 7 at this time with ffmpeg and having no probems at all

Answer (score 18):

You can also try using sox:

```
sox input.mp3 output.ogg
```

That should do the trick.

P.S: sox is available through yum on CentOS.

Comment: On Fedora 20, I also needed to package *sox-plugins-freeworld* from rpmfusion-free (for the MP3 suppport)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about sox-plugin-freeworld @AloisMahdal - got message "sox FAIL formats: no handler for file extension `mp3'" without that plugin.

Comment: I had to install `sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-mp3` with `sox` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fine audio/video conversion utility `avconv`. So are able to do:

```
 avconv -i file.mp3 file.ogg
```

Unlike `sox` it is able to convert also `aac`, and `webm` formats.