# How to convert an MP3 file to an Ogg Opus file?

Tags: converters, ogg, opus

Is there a converter that can convert MP3 files to [Ogg Opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format))?

Can you recommend one that can do it?

So far I've tried **Adobe Audition**, **Xilisoft Audio Converter Pro**, **WinAVI Video Converter**, and **Aimersoft Video Converter Pro**. None of them was useful.

Answer (score 27):

The easiest option is a command like this

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libopus output.opus
```

But there is a selection of parameters you can tweak, all documented [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopus-1).

E.g. I use the following command to compress audiobooks/podcasts (the resulting ~32 kbps OPUS files sound indistinguishable from 192 kbps MP3):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libopus -b:a 32k -vbr on -compression_level 10 -frame_duration 60 -application voip output.opus
```

- `-b:a 32k` sets bitrate to 32 kbps (or about 35 kbps in case of VBR), it can be reasonable to use 128k to compress music given a lossless (or a 320k MP3) original or 64k to compress music given a 192k MP3 original
- `-vbr on` turns variable bitrate mode on (may increase quality at cost of a using some additional kbits for some seconds)
- `-compression_level 10` commands to favour quality over compression speed
- `-frame_duration 60` increases quality at cost of 40 additional *milliseconds* of latency
- `-application voip` asks to do the best possible to save speech intelligibility, use `-application audio` for music

You can convert a set of many files this way in bash:

```
for f in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a libopus "${f%.*}.opus"; done
```

Comment: vbr is on by default, so you don't have to add it.

Answer (score 9):

### Convert MP3 files in all subfolders recursively and utilizing all CPU

***NOTE***: *FFmpeg multithread `-thread n` argument is ignored when encoding OPUS files.*

#### Preparing

Install [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), and MP3 with Opus codecs

```bash
sudo apt install -y parallel ffmpeg libmp3lame libopus
```

#### Usage

Recursive and using all CPUs:

- `find -iname "*.mp3" -type f` Find all MP3 files in whole directory
- `parallel -I% --max-args 1` Prepare `parallel` to use `%` char as argument for file path saving
- `-c:a opus` Set OPUS as encoder
- `-strict -2`  Enable FFmpeg to work with OPUS encoder
- `-b:a 128K -vbr on` Set OPUS at 128 KB/s (VBR) that is [enough to store stereo music](https://wiki.xiph.org/index.php?title=Opus_Recommended_Settings&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Recommended_Bitrates)
- `-map_metadata 0` Copy tags from MP3 to OPUS file
- `-compression_level 10` Favour quality over compression speed
- `-y` Overwrite OPUS file if already exists
- `touch -r % %.opus`  Use MP3 file's times instead of newly created files
- `rm -vf %` Remove MP3 file

```bash
find -iname "*.mp3" -type f | parallel -I% --max-args 1  \
  "ffmpeg -i % -strict -2 -c:a opus -b:a 128K -vbr on -map_metadata 0 -compression_level 10 -y %.opus;touch -r % %.opus;rm -vf %"
```

**NOTE**: Don't use `-frame_duration` argument for mixing audio purposes